# How to Sort <li> by Month Date & Year

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, listview

I need some help sorting the following list, I have done some research tried the following using JavaScript, but its not working as my date format  **January 20 2020**

Code:

```js
(function($) {
  var container = $(".sort-list");
  var items = $(".sort-item");

  items.each(function() {
    // Convert the string in 'data-event-date' attribute to a more
    // standardized date format
    var BCDate = $(this).attr("data-event-date").split("-");
    var standardDate = BCDate[1] + " " + BCDate[0] + " " + BCDate[2];
    standardDate = new Date(standardDate).getTime();
    $(this).attr("data-event-date", standardDate);

  });

  items.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = parseFloat($(a).attr("data-event-date"));
    b = parseFloat($(b).attr("data-event-date"));
    return a > b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0;
  }).each(function() {
    container.prepend(this);
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sort-list">
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="August 21 2020">August 21 2020</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="April 25 2020">April 25 2020</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="May 25 2020">May 25 2020</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="September 25 2020">September 25 2020</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="May 13 2020">May 13 2020</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="June 1 2020">June 1 2020</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="December 4 2020">December 4 2020</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `parseFloat`, why not `new Date()`?
Then you can simply compare the dates, see below

I removed the first `items.each` since I didn't understand its utility for the question here.

```js
(function($) {
  var container = $(".sort-list");
  var items = $(".sort-item");

  items.sort(function(a, b) {
    let d1 = new Date($(a).data("event-date"));
    let d2 = new Date($(b).data("event-date"));
    return d1 > d2 ? -1 : d1 < d2 ? 1 : 0;
  }).each(function() {
    container.prepend(this);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sort-list">
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="August 21 2020">August 21 2020</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="April 25 2020">April 25 2020</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="May 25 2020">May 25 2020</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="September 25 2020">September 25 2020</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="May 13 2020">May 13 2020</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="June 1 2020">June 1 2020</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="December 4 2020">December 4 2020</li>
</ul>
```

But, as suggested in comments and in another answer, it is better to convert the string, for example, "August 21 2020" to a simplified date format, something like "2020-08-21", then when transforming it into a real `Date` you will have more consistency

Comment: Creating two new `Date` objects is overhead not needed here. `parseInt()` would suffice rather than `parseFloat()` because `getTime()` always returns an integer, but I don't see a reason to compare an object to another object (that is, compare Dates) when you can compare values of the same primitive type (in this case, two numbers).  Seems like an extra step, and potentially an expensive one, and I'd argule not a best-practice one.  Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: You can include an answer by yourself if you found another good or better way, but since `data-event-date` is a string, I don't know how you suppose to transform "August 21 2020" into a float or integer...

Comment: I have, below. I don't see how you get a `Date()` from "August 21 2020" either by just passing that string to the constructor; it's not a format supported by all browsers. In my answer below I list the ones that are.

Comment: Ah, ok, now you said something that makes sense, the cross-browser... because the part about `new Date` being an extra step makes no sense, since for your solution and for `getTime` you need to create a `Date` object in the same way, you just changed the value that you passed to the constructor

Answer (score 0):

The only formats that `Date()` can parse cross-platform are

- 2011-10-10 (date-only form)
- 2011-10-10T14:48:00 (date-time form)
- 2011-10-10T14:48:00.000+09:00 (date-time form with milliseconds and time zone)

That's from MDN's `Date()` documentation. Anything else that might appear to work could be working on your browser but not others. (And your format - "21 August 2020 - looks like one that some browsers might try to handle, maybe, but certainly not a cross-browser solution.)  If your source format is "August 21 2020", you'll probably need to add some logic to parse, for example, "August" to "08" (month name to *padded* month number). And similarly pad less-than-10 days-of-month.  Just be careful of any solutions that don't follow one of the three cross-browser-supported formats above, per MDN.

Other than that, your code looks like it's doing the right thing - although you want to use `parseInt()` instead of `parseFloat()` when comparing the dates; `getTime()` always returns an integer.  `parseFloat()` here is overkill.

Hope this helps!